# Range function in prime numbers program

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is a program for printing prime numbers from 2 and 11.

```
for num in range(2,12):
    prime = True
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num%i==0):
            prime = False
    if prime:
       print num
```

In the second for-loop during the last iteration the value of the num=11 .. so the range should take num as 10 i.e (n-1) but in this program value 11 is still getting printed .. how is that?

Comment: Also, you have `range(2, 12)`, that includes 11, why wouldn't it be printed? It's a prime number.

Comment: I'd rather calling them odd numbers which are accidentally primes too, if you increase the numbers a bit you get results that are not prime.

Answer (score 0):

`num` is indeed 11, and it is `num` that is being printed:

```
if prime:
    print num
```

The `range(2, num)` range goes from 2 through to 10, inclusive, but the `for` loop over that range uses `i` as the target, not `num`:

```
for i in range(2, num):
#   ^  the target of the for loop
```

So it is the **value of `i`, not `num`** that goes from 2 through to 10, and `i` is never printed. The value of `num` is not changed by the inner loop, it remains set to 11 all the way through. So yes, it'd be *surprising* if `10` was printed instead.

Note that the `print num` line is only ever executed if `prime` is still set to `True`. It would be set to `False` if `num` was divisible by any of the `i` values. For `11`, there is no value between 2 and 10 (inclusive) that can divide 11, so `prime` remains set to `True` and `num` is printed.